# I want to convert Arabic numerals “٠,١,٢,٣,٤,٥,٦,٧,٨,٩” from whole document into English numerals using Word Macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with the arabic documents, But i am facing number conversion issues. So, i need a macro to convert the arabic digits to english numbers.

Comment: Use the same technique you used for finding and replacing arabic words.  You will just need 10 find/replace, 1 for each numeral.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get the best answers from this community you need to do some research and attempt to write the code yourself. Then come back when you get stuck. We can then look at your code. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two macros convert numbers in the *selected* range between Western and Arabic/Persian. The code also provides for numbers written left-to-right and for right-to-left - the supplied function does the reversing. Comments in the code show how to change the text direction and which source/target scripts to use.

```
Sub WesternNumberToArabic_or_Persian()
Dim Rng As Range, StrTmp As String, i As Long
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Text = "[,.0-9]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Sub
    If .Characters.Last Like "[.,]" Then .End = .End - 1
    ' If the numbers are input right-to-left, use:
    StrTmp = Reverse(.Text)
    ' If the numbers are input left-to-right, use:
    StrTmp = .Text
    For i = 0 To 9
      ' For arabic #s, use
      StrTmp = Replace(StrTmp, Chr(48 + i), ChrW(17632 + i))
      ' For persian #s, use
      StrTmp = Replace(StrTmp, Chr(48 + i), ChrW(1776 + i))
    Next i
    .Text = StrTmp
    .Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub

Sub Arabic_or_PersianNumberToWestern()
Dim Rng As Range, StrTmp As String, i As Long
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    'For arabic #s, use:
    .Text = "[,." & ChrW(1632) & "-" & ChrW(1641) & "]{1,}"
    'For persian #s, use:
    .Text = "[,." & ChrW(1776) & "-" & ChrW(1785) & "]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Sub
    If .Characters.Last Like "[.,]" Then .End = .End - 1
    ' If the numbers are input right-to-left, use:
    StrTmp = Reverse(.Text)
    ' If the numbers are input left-to-right, use:
    StrTmp = .Text
    For i = 0 To 9
      ' For arabic #s, use:
      StrTmp = Replace(StrTmp, ChrW(1632 + i), Chr(48 + i))
      ' For persian #s, use:
      StrTmp = Replace(StrTmp, ChrW(1776 + i), Chr(48 + i))
    Next i
    .Text = StrTmp
    .Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub

Function Reverse(StrTmp As String) As String
  If (Len(StrTmp) > 1) Then
    Reverse = Reverse(Mid$(StrTmp, 2)) + Left$(StrTmp, 1)
  Else
    Reverse = StrTmp
  End If
End Function
```

To have the code run on an entire document, replace:

```
Dim Rng As Range, StrTmp As String, i As Long
Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Selection.Range
```

with:

```
Dim StrTmp As String, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
```

and delete:

```
If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Have you test this code on dummy text. Both(western to Arabic and Arabic to Western) !!!

Comment: I tried arabic to western code but non of the arabic number is converted to english. I also tried on signle arabic digit but nothing happened and received no error as well.

Comment: @MAhad Did you make the appropriate adjustments where indicated by the comments in the code? And did you actually select the range to process?

Comment: I did the necessary changes to run the code according to given comments, but nothing happened. Would you recommend me the changes require to successfully run the code.

Comment: I am working on the  arabic/persian to westren converting code.

Comment: To Convert from Arabic to Western, use the Arabic_or_PersianNumberToWestern macro and comment-out the lines for Persian #s, viz: *.Text = "[,." & ChrW(1776) & "-" & ChrW(1785) & "]{1,}"* and *StrTmp = Replace(StrTmp, ChrW(1776 + i), Chr(48 + i))*.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply but what if the values are like this (٣,٣۶٨,٣٣٣). How can I replace the brackets with the brackets?

Comment: I don't understand your question - the macro does nothing to brackets and it's by no means clear what you mean by 'replace the brackets with the brackets'.

Comment: ١٣١٠۴۶ ٣۴ ٣٧٠٣٣٣ ٧٣٣۵٧۴ above macro is not converting these values.

Comment: I think the character's code for the Persian digits is not included into the code. the Persian code only convert 4 and 5 while rest of the digits remain the same.

Comment: You asked for code to convert Arabic. I gave you code that and convert Arabic *or* Persian. Your numbers use a mix of Arabic *and* Persian characters. It's little wonder, then, that the Persian characters don't convert from Arabic to Western...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert all arabic numerals in your document to English just follow these steps:

go to word option -> advanced -> select numerals and set it to Arabic, and you will find all the numbers changed to English

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer but i need a macro to solve my problem.

Comment: If you want to use macros, you can check the article here: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/convert-numbers-currency-to-words-with-excel-vba and try to modify it for your needs